# При нажатие на ссылку текст ссылки передается в div блок

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать текст ссылки по нажатию на нее в определенный блок.

На пример

```html
<a href="" class="letter"> a </a>
<a href="" class="letter"> b </a>
<a href="" class="letter"> c </a>
```

И текст ссылки то есть буквы передается в определенный блок

Результат

```html
<div class="reslink"> a или b или c </div>
```

или другая буква, заменяемая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это надо?

```js
const d = document.querySelector('div');

[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    d.textContent = a.textContent;
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: gray;
}

div {
display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="letter"> a </a>
<a href="" class="letter"> b </a>
<a href="" class="letter"> c </a>

<div class="reslink"></div>
```